# WebAPI and Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I can't seem to find an answer to this question so I'm posting it here.  This may be a basic routing question and perhaps I'm just missing something obvious.  I have a WebAPI2 project that has GetAll() method in the controller.  I'm using Attribute Routing including a RoutePrefix.  When I test the method using Postman it works fine http://localhost/api/v1/Suppressions and it returns a list of JSON from my Mongo DB collection.  By chance during testing I happened to test and added a parameter to the URL thinking I would receive a "The resource cannot be found" error http://localhost/api/v1/Suppressions?name=abc but it instead called the GetAll() method.

During routing are parameters ignored and is the URI the only thing used (unless, of course, I have a method that specifically named the parameters like Get(string name))?  If that's the case, is there a route constraint that I need to add to my GetAll() method in order to throw the "The resource annot be found" error if someone inadvertently called the method with a parameter or list of parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query parameters are ignored in routing, unless they specified in the Uri.  You can either add a separate route for 'Suppressions?name={name}' or handle it within your existing call.

For information on Uri matching, see: [UriTemplate.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate.match(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Question though, how would I handle it in my existing call if my method GetAll() doesn't accept parameters?  How would I know the user called the API with parameters if the routing thinks it's fine?

Comment: You can get the query parameter value using [HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ah, right.  Thanks for your help!  Both answers were helpful but I'm accepting this answer due to the answer stating that query parameters are ignored during routing which does answer the original question.  And the reminder that I can use HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString to get the parameters and return a 404 if desired.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Let's say that you have a method like the one that you are describing. For example,

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class api: ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Supressions")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll(HttpRequestMessage request){
      ///etc
    }
}
```

This method will be called no matter what parameters you use.

However, if you do something like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class api: ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Supressions/{abc}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request, string abc){
      ///etc
    }
}
```

You will need the parameter. If you don't have it and you call http://localhost/api/Suppressions, it will return something like this:

```
{
"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:64307/api/Suppressions'.",
"messageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named ''."
}
```

Now, when you have multiple parameters, you can do something like this, and if you don't use them in your call, it's going to complain as well

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class api: ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Supressions")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request, string abc, int id, int somethingElse){
      ///etc
    }
}
```

Here the call would be something like this:

http://localhost:64307/api/Suppressions?abc=asdas&id=13&somethingElse=45

Hope this help you understand

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So typically in this scenario where there is just one method in a controller that's parameterless, is there a route constraint or something that needs to be added to the method in order to verify the call was correctly routed to the method or should I not care and if the user inadvertently added query string parameters for some reason it just calls GetAll() and returns everything and they fix it on their end?

Comment: No problem. Why the user would be able to modify the query string? Isn't that been handled by your front end routing framework? I'm not aware if there exist a constraint for this.

Comment: You're correct, the front end will never call the method with parameters.  It was more of a QA testing thing when using Postman.  Thanks for your help!